# $f$ is of $C^2$ therefore $g\circ f$ is of $C^2$, for all functions $g$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have some functions $f$ which is twice differentiable, and some function $g$ of which I don't know it's smoothness or differentiability. Is the function $h$ = $g\circ f$ twice differentiable?

Comment: you  can take the derivative of $g\circ f$ twice and see which conditions are required.

Comment: What happens if $f$ is the identity function?

Comment: Is the identify function twice differentiable?

Comment: @pafnuti of course, it's smooth, Like every other polynomial function.

Comment: The product of convolution is the operation you search for, it agrees with differentiability because $(g*f)^{(n)}=g*f^{(n)}$. So as long as $f$ is smooth then $g*f$ is smooth no matter what $g$ is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at

$$f\left(x\right)=x$$

and

$$g\left(x\right)=\begin{cases}1&x\geq0\\-1&x<0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is not true. For instance,
$$g\circ f(x) = |x|. $$